# Fill a list with a range of formated strings in python

Tags: python, list

Why this does not work?

```
[ print("%d03" % a) for a in range(1,99)]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [ print("%d03" % a) for a in range(1,99)]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but

> print("%03d" % a)
>       098

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.x, `print` is a *statement*, so it cannot appear as part of an *expression*.  In Python 3.x, the list comprehension would be syntactically correct because `print` was turned into a function, though a bit pointless since `print()` always returns `None`.

In any case, this is the right way to do it:

```
for a in range(1,99):
    print("%d03" % a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `print()` is a function that *prints* the arguments, but does not *return* them. Good news is that you don't need `print()` for formatting.

What you (probably) are looking for is:

```
["%03d" % a for a in range(1,99)]
```

or using the built in function `format()`:

```
[format(a, "03d") for a in range(1,99)]
```

If you indeed want to `print()` the numbers, then don't use list comprehension, but just a simple `for` loop:

```
for _ in range(99): print("%03d" % _)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't use print in a list comprehension, but you can work around it:

```
In: print ["%03d" % a for a in range(1,10)]
['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('\n'.join(['%d03' % i for i in range(1,99)]))
```

print doesn't return anything so you can't use it in an expression.